# Select elements with unique values

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

I'm trying to parse an OpenOffice spreadsheet to obtain rows with unique values in the first column.

I.E., I would like to retrieve from the following XML fragment all `<table:table-row>` elements with unique `<text:p>` values in the first child `<table:table-cell>`.

```
    <table:table table:name="foo">
        <table:table-row>
            <table:table-cell>
                <text:p>1</text:p>
            </table:table-cell>
            <table:table-cell>
                <text:p>foo</text:p>
            </table:table-cell>
        </table:table-row>
        <table:table-row>
            <table:table-cell>
                <text:p>2</text:p>
            </table:table-cell>
            <table:table-cell>
                <text:p>bar</text:p>
            </table:table-cell>
        </table:table-row>
        <table:table-row>
            <table:table-cell>
                <text:p>1</text:p>
            </table:table-cell>
            <table:table-cell>
                <text:p>baz</text:p>
            </table:table-cell>
        </table:table-row>
    </table:table>
```

I'll like to get the below output as Nodes

```
        <table:table-row>
            <table:table-cell>
                <text:p>1</text:p>
            </table:table-cell>
            <table:table-cell>
                <text:p>foo</text:p>
            </table:table-cell>
        </table:table-row>
        <table:table-row>
            <table:table-cell>
                <text:p>2</text:p>
            </table:table-cell>
            <table:table-cell>
                <text:p>bar</text:p>
            </table:table-cell>
        </table:table-row>
```

How can I do this with XPath?

Comment: XPath is just an expression to get a defined Elemente|Attribute|Node of your dom. What you would like is to transform your initial XML file to another. You do that by using XSLT and then using XPath expression using XSLT.

Comment: I wanted to get Nodes, didn't occur to me that I could get XML too.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XPath produces desired output:
`/table:table/table:table-row[not(./table:table-cell[1]/text:p/text() = preceding-sibling::table:table-row/table:table-cell[1]/text:p/text())]`

Answer (score 0):

Pure XPath should be:

```
 /table:table/table:*[not(
  .//text:p[1]
   = preceding-sibling::table:table-row//text:p[1]
 )]
```

**If with expected output you mean a sequence of `table:row` nodes and not an xml document as someone correctly notice in the comments**.

```
 /table:table/table:*[not(
  ./table:*[1]//text:*[1]
   = preceding-sibling::table:*/table:*[1]/text:*[1]
 )]
```

Comment: I don't understand your XPath expression but this produces an extra empty node for me.  Thanks for the code and clarification though.

Comment: @polishchuk answer is much more safe because is an absolute XPath perhaps a bit verbous. I've given you a short one (perfectly working on your question input), which must be tuned according to the knowledge you have of your input xml (and of XPath :)). Just for correctness, I've edited the question with a safer XPath which should be less general, but safer.